# How to mine empty blocks?

Tags: mining, daemon

I just want to mine an empty block with a daemon I am running. Do I need to change the code significantly or is there a setting?

Also do I still get a reward?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to change the code significantly or is there a setting?

There is no "setting", so you either change the code (where the block template is filled with pending transactions) or fetch a block template straight after a block is mined (e.g. when the tx pool is empty), then find the solution before some other miner.

> Also do I still get a reward?

Yes (assuming you mine the block before someone else of course).

Comment: Now are there any advantages like I was assuming?

Comment: With mpty blocks you only get the subsidy (emission), with transactions you also collect the tx fees.